# Animate text using CSS for "slideshow"

Tags: html, css, animation, text

I'm trying to create a slideshow of sorts for just text. The closest thing I can come across are flash animations or scrolling marquees, which I do not want. I want to turn the banner below (which is an animated gif) into a slideshow with text using CSS.

http://www.crystalimagesinc.com/banner_animation.gif

The following link is as close to what I want to do as I can find, though it's not very good (and kind of messes with other elements on the page).

http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-news-ticker

What is a clean, relatively simple way to create a banner or "slideshow" of text, preferably in CSS?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: You can pick apart the example to get what you want.  If using pure css, you use a transform, with or without keyframes.